# How to programmatically select a row in UITableView in MonoTouch?

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios

I know you can select a row in a UITableView by calling UITableView.SelectRow function, but I'm having trouble to construct the first parameter NSIndexPath for the given row number. This is the code I tried:

```
NSIndexPath path = new NSIndexPath() { Row = 3 };
tableView.SelectRow(path, false, UITableViewScrollPosition.None);
```

But it doesn't compile because Row is read-only.

Or maybe there is a different way to do it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the NSIndexPath.FromRowSection static method instead:

```
NSIndexPath path = NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(3, 0);
```

Comment: This is great. Why didn't I come up with this? Thank you very much!

Comment: you saved my sanity, I was spinning my wheels until I found this, thank you!