# Xamarin.ios-- Select first row of TableView as default?

Tags: uitableview, xamarin

I have a simple TableViewController. I implemented UITableViewSource to load the data. But how can I set the first row selected as default?

I know how to do it in ios: 
[Select First Row as default in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728152/select-first-row-as-default-in-uitableview)

But it seems there is no correspond method in Xamarin.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically select a row in UITableView in MonoTouch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206699/how-to-programmatically-select-a-row-in-uitableview-in-monotouch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just searched the api and find out how to set up the NSIndexPath

http://macapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:MonoMac.Foundation.NSIndexPath

And the question is solved.